# Nestjs How to correctly handle exceptions on controller using multer library?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs, multer

I'm trying to create a service to upload specific files from Post multipart/form-data request and I found a easy way to validate the fields count and name sent using FileInterceptor decorator imported from @nestjs/platform-express. I don't understand how to return these validations to the call. I tried to follow a basic example detailed on github repository but It seems to be wrong. Do you have any idea? Thanks!!!

[expressjs multer github](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {limits: {fields: 5}}))
    uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
        if (multer.MulterError) {
            throw new BadRequestException('Max fields allowed are 5')
        }

        return 'ok'
    }
```

Comment: I think error is thrown before the code reaches to the controller. So, there's no way you can catch the error at the controller level.

Comment: Do you know the way to catch these errors?

Comment: Use global filters

Answer (score 2):

As Istiyak Tailor mentions the exception is raised before entering your controller logic.

How I managed to get around the issue was to from the MulterOptions fileFilter function to raise an UnsupportedMediaTypeException when calling the callback function.

```
import { UnsupportedMediaTypeException } from '@nestjs/common';

export const excelFilesFilter = (
  req: any,
  file: { originalname: string },
  callback: (error: Error, acceptFile: boolean) => any,
) => {
  if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(xls|xlsx)$/)) {
    callback(
      new UnsupportedMediaTypeException('Only excel files are allowed'),
      false,
    );
  }
  callback(null, true);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use MulterError to handle errors but it can't custom message. It only match some case errors. Almost forgot, I was validate and handle file upload in FileInterceptor not UploadedFile decorator.

```
 @Post('addOne')
      @UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor('image', {
          fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
            if (file.originalname.match(/^.*\.(jpg|webp|png|jpeg)$/))
              cb(null, true);
            else cb(new MulterError('LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE', 'image'), false);
          } 
        }),
      )
```